# How to normalize counts in stat_binhex in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a `data.frame`, with two variables, measuring parameters for two classes with very different amount of data for each class (~2500 samples vs ~100000 samples).

Sample code:

```
plot.gg <- ggplot(data=rbind(
                    data.frame(x=rnorm(2500, m=0.41, sd=0.1), y=rnorm(2500, m=12000, sd=1000), type="A"),
                    data.frame(x=rnorm(100000, m=0.60, sd=0.1), y=rnorm(100000, m=6000, sd=1000), type="B")
                  ),
              mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, colour=type, group=type)
             ) + geom_hex(alpha=0.3)

plot.gg
```

Result:
[image]

Here, single color palette is used for both classes, which has resulted in uniform gray fill for class A.
I would like to have a separate color palette for class A, to see its distribution also.

Another acceptable variant would be normalizing data to see percentage instead of counts. However, I cannot figure out, how to use `..count..` and `(..count..)/sum(..count..)`.

I also need `alpha` in `geom_hex` to see overlap in classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found. The solution is `aes(fill=..density..)` in `geom_hex`.

```
plot.gg <- ggplot(data=rbind(
                       data.frame(x=rnorm(2500, m=0.41, sd=0.1), y=rnorm(2500, m=12000, sd=1000), type="A"),
                       data.frame(x=rnorm(100000, m=0.60, sd=0.1), y=rnorm(100000, m=6000, sd=1000), type="B")
),
mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, colour=type, group=type)) + geom_hex(alpha=0.6, aes(fill=..density..))

plot.gg
```

I've also increased `alpha`, because it now gives better look.